# How to open new browser window on button click event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to open new browser window on button click event in C# ASP.NET?

Please share any example.

I am doing following code. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

```
btn_Click()
{
    if(condition==true)
    {
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
            this.GetType(),
            "page_index_script2", 
            "openNewWindow();", 
            true
        );
    }
}
```

And the JavaScript function is

```
function openNewWindow()
{
    alert('HI');
    window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com');  
}
```

When I run the code from javascript function Alert works but new window is not getting opened.

Comment: You want the new window to be opened before handling the event on the code behind or just going to some link in a new window?

Comment: Please don't add things like " C# ASP.NET" to the end of your titles. That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use some code like this, you can adjust a height and width as per your need

```
    protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // open a pop up window at the center of the page.
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", "var Mleft = (screen.width/2)-(760/2);var Mtop = (screen.height/2)-(700/2);window.open( 'your_page.aspx', null, 'height=700,width=760,status=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,location=no,top=\'+Mtop+\', left=\'+Mleft+\'' );", true);
    }
```

Comment: How do you prevent this popup script from being ran when navigating back to the page?

Comment: @JamesWierzba Can you not check url referrer or something? I think that should work.

Answer (score 10):

It can be done all on the client-side using the `OnClientClick`*<sup>[[MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx)</sup>* event handler and `window.open`*<sup>[[MDN]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open)</sup>*:

```
<asp:Button 
     runat="server" 
     OnClientClick="window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com'); return false;">
     Open a new window!
</asp:Button>
```

Comment: I tried all the back end mode but this was the easiest. In Code-Behind, I'd do wall the necessary checks and build the URL, then hook it to the OnClientClick in this fashion - btnButton.OnClientClick = "window.open('"+ customURL +"'); return false;"; This works for both Buttons and LinkButtons (in my case).

Comment: This was perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Response.Write('... javascript that opens a window...')

http://www.aspspider.com/qa/Question2714.aspx

Comment: Side note: such code will run against "popup blocker" checks in a browser and normally will result in no-op (could have worked back 2008 when it was answered).

Comment: Yes, of course we must always worry about the features of the actual browser when dealing with popup windows.

Comment: the link in answer is broken

Answer (score 2):

Or write to the response stream:

```
Response.Write("<script>");
Response.Write("window.open('page.html','_blank')");
Response.Write("</script>");
```