# asp:Hyperlink in Gridview open PDF in new browser window

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, gridview, hyperlink

I currently have a gridview that dynamically creates `asp:Hyperlinks` to PDF files.  Right now, the url just downloads the file to the local machine.  What's the easiest way to get them to open in a new window so the user has the option to print or download.  Chrome automatically downloads it.  IE asks to open or save it.  I just want it to open in a browser window.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="lblProductName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' NavigateUrl="#" Target="_blank"  ></asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And the actual NavigateUrl gets created in the code behind

```
HyperLink lblProductName = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("lblProductName");
lblProductName.NavigateUrl = urlLink;
```

Comment: Chrome downloading it is the browser functionality.

Comment: & So is the IE asking to open and save functionality of the IE

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056103/how-to-open-new-browser-window-on-button-click-event refer this i think u might get the answer and need to tweak a little

Comment: Opening or downloading is a user setting of his/her own browser. You cannot control what will happen once the link is clicked.

Comment: It can happen if some how u find the code that it adds a [Ctrl] on his keyboard to the userclick

Comment: @VDWWD I guess what he wants Is, like when u click on it, preview opens the file in new tab readable format . Something like when u want to view the file in yahoo mail

Answer (score 1):

Add a new page say DownloadFile.aspx and add the following code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!this.IsPostBack)
{
    string fileName = Request.QueryString["pdffile"];
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/PDFs/") + fileName;
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    Response.WriteFile(path);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
}
```

Now in GridView remove LinkButton and add HyperLink as shown below

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Target = "_Blank" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("FileName","DownloadFile.aspx?PDFFile={0}") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```