# Can't open pop-up window in Chrome using c#/ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, hyperlink, popupwindow

I have code that dynamically builds a series of hyperlinks based on the contents of a file folder. When I run the code and click on a link, I get a pop-up window, but it's blank. This is C# in an ASP.Net 4.6.1 web page using Chrome. Here's my code:

```
        TableRow newRow = new TableRow();
        string foldername = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["oid"]) + "\\";
        string pathString = Server.MapPath("~/Files/");
        string completePath = Path.Combine(pathString + foldername);
        if (Directory.Exists(completePath))
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(completePath);
            int cellCount = 0;
            foreach (string foundfile in files)
            {
                TableCell newCell = new TableCell();
                newCell.BorderColor = Color.Black;
                newCell.BorderWidth = Unit.Parse("1px");
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(foundfile);
                HyperLink hl = new HyperLink();
                hl.NavigateUrl = completePath + filename;
                hl.Text = filename;
                hl.Target = "_blank";
                hl.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open(this.href, 'child', 'height=400, width=600,scrollbars'); return false");
                if (cellCount == 0 || (cellCount % 3) == 0)
                {
                    newRow = new TableRow();
                    taSpecs.Rows.Add(newRow);
                }
                newCell.Controls.Add(hl);
                newRow.Cells.Add(newCell);
                cellCount++;
            }
        }
```

The files exist, and if I copy the URL from one of the links to File Explorer, it opens the file without a problem. Chrome has the pop-up blocker turned off. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Chrome blocking unsafe scripts? Tried `_new` instead of blank?

Comment: Yes, _new doesn't work either, but thanks anyway.

Comment: I solved my problem by using this technique: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652249/asphyperlink-in-gridview-open-pdf-in-new-browser-window/44653802#44653802